# What's interval to validate the idle object in Apache Commons Pool 2

Tags: java, apache-commons-pool

I am using `Apache Commons Pool 2`, I have set the configuration `testWhileIdle` to true, which means that the Pool framework will check whether the idle objects they are valid.

I would ask whether this check occurs periodically, if so, what's the default interval, and how i can change it.

I ask so because the objects in the pool should periodically connect to the server to keep alive, and I think pool's `validateObject` method is a good place to fulfill this.

Per @user7294900's comments,there are two configuration parameters:

1. `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis`, default value is -1
2. `minEvictableIdleTimeMillis`, default value is 1800*60*30

I have following two question:

1. What's the difference between these two parameters?
2. I set both of them to 5000, and I have 8 objects in the pool, I print the object's hashcode in my PooledObjectFactory's `validateObject` method, I found that only 3 objects'hash code has been printed out, then there is no more messages printed again, looks the `validateObject` 's is not called every 5 seconds or the call to `validateObject` is stuck?

***I figured out the problem, please see the comments***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use\update `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` for changing time of idle validation, see [Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html).

> timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis  (int) The number of milliseconds to
>   sleep between runs of the idle connection validation/cleaner thread.
>   This value should not be set under 1 second. It dictates how often we
>   check for idle, abandoned connections, and how often we validate idle
>   connections. The default value is 5000 (5 seconds).

Comment: Thanks @user7294900 for you answer,I updated my question per your comments,could you please take a look?

Comment: Sorry,I figured out the problem...`timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` is the interval  to schedule task to validate the objects, and `minEvictableIdleTimeMillis` is the idle time that will be evicted from pool.Since the two parameters are the same, seems that eviction wins

Comment: Default value of minEvictableIdleTimeMillis  is 1000* 60 * 30